# Static objects of nested class can be declared without class definition

Tags: c++, static, nested-class

A static object of a class cannot be declared unless the class has been defined...

For example..the following code does not compile as the class C has not been defined....

```
class C;
int main()
{
    static C y;
}
```

But why does the following code compiles even though class B has not been defined??

```
class A
{
    class B;
    static B x;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case (in `main` function) the object `y` is defined - so the class definition is required.

In the second case (in class `A`) the member `x` is only declared - it needs to be defined anyway normally in .cpp file. In the point of its definition the definition of `C` will be required, but it is not for static member declaration.

Comment: To expand on this, if `x` was declared as a non-static member this wouldn't compile because non-static members are *defined* in the class scope, not just *declared*.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not that one class is an inner class and the other one isn't. The difference is that `static` means something different in class scope and in function scope.

In class scope, it means a class-wide (not per-instance) member, and the line is a *declaration*. You need a separate definition outside the class body:

```
A::B A::x; // B must be complete here, and you can add an initializer
```

In function scope, it's a local variable of static storage duration, meaning that it will retain its value across function calls. The line is a definition by itself, not just a declaration, so it needs the complete type.

Answer (score 1):

> A static object of a class cannot be declared unless the class has been defined...

Not quite. It can't be *defined* (or instantiated, if you like) unless the class has been defined (and so is a *complete type*); it can be *declared* as long as the class has been declared (but might be an *incomplete type*, not yet defined).

> the following code does not compile as the class C has not been defined....

Indeed, it tried to define a local variable, which requires the class definition.

> But why does the following code compiles even though class B has not been defined??

Because you're only declaring the static variable. To use the variable, it will also need a definition (exactly one, typically in a source file)

```
A::B A::x;
```

and the type must be complete (that is, defined) at that point.